# appengine `npm install` error

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, npm, npm-install

Hello I like to ask something about nodejs google appengine, I just follow the instruction here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/quickstart

but after `npm install` step I got this error :

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.15063
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\mulky\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "update"
npm ERR! node v6.3.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.6
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET

npm ERR! network tunneling socket could not be established, cause=self signed certificate
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\Repo\GCP\nodejs-docs-samples\appengine\hello-world\npm-debug.log
```

please help me to solve this, thanks :)

NOTE: I think I dont have any network issues, and I dont use any proxy, ohh for your information I already re-install nodejs including npm but it still show the same error.

Comment: The NPM error suggests this may be related to a network issue.  Were you experiencing any network issues as the time when this was occurred?  If not, can you reliably reproduce this issue?  If so, are you in fact behind a proxy?  Including the answers to these questions in your question would be helpful for the community to rule out common causes of `ECONNRESET` errors.

Comment: Hi @Nicholas thanks for your advice, I think I dont have any network issues, and I dont use any proxy, ohh for your information I already re-install nodejs including npm but it still show the same error.

Comment: Are you able to run `npm install` with any JS application, even one that is not for App Engine?  If not, then I would suspect this is a system network connectivity issue or an issue with NPM failing to persist TCP connections on your system.  Is this on your local machine?

Comment: @Nicholas thanks for your support I already fix this problem, I found that I have wrong env last time :)